# Monitor or review path when debugging in VS Code

Tags: debugging, back, backtrace, debug-backtrace

Can I do backtracing while debugging my code in VS Code?
I would to monitor and review execution path of a program. Would like to see stepping backward through the program to view the actual sequence of instructions that lead to the current breakpoint.

I tried to explore command palette options for Debugging.